# svelte:element with dynamic this and spread attributes

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

In the code example below, when I use `...props`, there is no problem:

```html
<svelte:element this="div" {...props}>
    this is div !
</svelte:element>
```

But when I try to make `this` dynamic, even with a simple string, I get an error saying `props is not defined`.

```html
<svelte:element this={"div"} {...props}>
    this is div !
</svelte:element>
```

###### Reproduction

https://svelte.dev/repl/1c5c200152784ab9802b2333b01124f1?version=4.1.2

###### Logs

```bash
Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined
```

Comment: Didn't you already open [an issue about this](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/9092)?